# re.search() con condicional "if" para strings cortos o sin dígitos

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Tengo el siguiente código cuya idea es que imprima un mensaje en caso de que un string sea menor a 5 o no tenga ningún dígito, sin embargo no funciona correctamente.

```
x="string123"
if len(x)<=5 or re.search(r"[^\d]",x):
     print("wrong")
```

El output del código es `wrong`, lo cual me parece raro ya que `x` tiene más de 5 carácteres y contiene dígitos.

¿Alguien me podría ayudar a identificar el problema? Por favor no planteen soluciones alternativas a alguna con regex ya que la idea de este código es practicar expresiones regulares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu condición es "string sea menor a 5 o **no tenga ningún dígitos**".
`r"[^\d]` busca **cualquier carácter que no sea un dígito**, por lo que en tu caso la salida de `re.search` va a ser evaluada como `True` ya que **hay caracteres que no son dígitos**. La condición debería ser en todo caso:

```
import re

x="string123"
if len(x)<=5 or not re.search(r"\d", x):
     print("wrong")
```

O verlo en positivo...

```
if len(x) > 5 and re.search(r"\d", x):
    print("wraigt")
else:
    print("wrong")
```

Para verlo más claro puedes usar `re.findall`:

```
>>> print(re.findall(r"[^\d]",x))
['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

Lo que en realidad equivale a :

```
>>> print(re.findall(r"\D",x))
['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

Comment: Entendido,con el re.findall ya todo se ve mejor. Gracias por responderme tantas preguntas!

Answer (score 3):

> que imprima un mensaje en caso de que un string sea menor a 5 o no tenga ningún dígito
>
> la idea de este código es practicar expresiones regulares

Cuando se usa:

```
re.search(r"[^\d]",x)
```

la expresión regular coincide con el primer caracter que se cualquier caracter excepto dígitos. Por eso, la expresión regular coincide:

```
     "string123"
#     ^
#    acá (la "s" es un caracter que no es un dígito)
```

y por lo tanto, la condición del if será verdadera. Y en realidad ese patrón es lo mismo que `r"\D"`.

Se puede cambiar a que coincida

- si tiene al menos un dígito (negando el resultado del método)

  ```
    r"\d"
  ```
- o, si no tiene ningún dígito, viendo desde el inicio del string hasta el final:

  ```
    r"^\D*$"
  ```

Y, ya que te interesa practicar regex, podemos usar este último, combinando a las 2 condiciones en una: que no tenga ningún dígito (`^\D*$`) o que tenga un largo de 4 o menos (`^.{0,4}$`).

**Regex**:

```
^(?:\D*|.{0,4})$
```

Descripción:

- `^` ::: inicio del texto
- `(?:`…`)` ::: es un grupo que coincide con `\D*|.{0,4}` (una opción **o** la otra):

  - `\D*` ::: 0 o más caracteres que no son dígitos, o
  - `.{0,4}` ::: 0 a 4 caracteres cualesquiera.
- `$` ::: el fin del texto.

Usando además el modificador [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) para que el punto también coincida con saltos de línea.

**Código**:

```
import re

x = "string123"
regex = r"^(?:\D*|.{0,4})$"

if re.search(regex, x, re.DOTALL):
    print ("No tiene dígitos o el largo es menor a 5")
```

Comment: Anda... no se me ocurrió  la posibilidad de unir ambas  condiciones en una sola expresión regular. "Mastering regular expressions with Mariano"  ツ

Comment: @FJSevilla jaja, es que mejor usar un if antes que complicarse, tal cual respondiste. Pero leí "*practicar expresiones regulares*" y no pude evitar ir un paso más ;-)